# Changing XML request into a Java object

Tags: java, xml, object, transformation

I just had a quick question regarding how I would go about transforming an XML request into a Java Object.

Can I just declare all of the fields as variables and then use `@XmlElement / @XmlAttribute` annotations to declare which variables would be `elements / attributes`?

I can clarify if needed!

Comment: Why don't you simply try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Pretty sure, you're looking for JAXB. Here is a tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you need, but usually adding @XmlRootElement to the class is all you need.